# Can I use private backing variables with Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have the following code in my class:

```
    private int order;
    public int Order {
        get { return order; }
        set { order = value; }
        }
    }
```

I tested it out by trying the following and it works okay. Can someone tell me is this a legal thing for me to do? In the past I have always used the following:

```
    public int Order { get; set; }
```

Is there any difference between this and doing it manually other than the manual way requires more typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very little difference and in my opinion, not required unless you need to do some manipulation of the private member on the get or set.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Yes I did want to do some manipulation. What I was really confused about was how Azure knows what to do when I start naming private variables rather than use those created by the compiler.

Comment: Windows Azure (rather the WCF Data Services client library) only serializes public properties.